# Stepwise selection method in (SAS 9.3) PROC REG

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I'm running a multivariate linear regression model in SAS (v. 9.3) using the REG procedure with the stepwise statement, as follows below:

(1) Set the regressors list:

```
%let regressors = x1 x2 x3;
```

(2) Run the procedure:

```
ods output DWStatistic=DW ANOVA=F_Fisher parameterestimates=beta CollinDiag=Collinearita outputstatistics=residui fitstatistics=rsquare;



proc reg data=base_dati outest=reg_multivar edf;


model TD&eq. = &regressors. /selection=stepwise`SLSTAY=&signif_amm_multivar_stay. SLENTRY=&signif_amm_multivar_entry. VIF COLLIN adjrsq DW R influence noint;

output out=diagnostic;

quit;

ods output close;
```

By adding one regressor to the list, let's say x4, to the macro-variable &regressors., the beta value estimates change, although the selected variables are the same ones.

In practice, in both cases the variables chosen from such selection method are x1 and x2, but beta parameters for x1 and x2 change in the second case with respect to the second case.

Could you provide an explanation for that?

It would be nice to have a reference for such explanation.

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: You have an extra ` in your code, is that present in your actual code or a typo here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you have missing data. SAS removes records row wise. So if you include 2 more variables that happen to have a few missing those entire records will be missing which means you're not actually using the exact same data between each regression model.

Comment: Thank @Reeza! That's the only possible explanation; I wondered about this and I thought it was my error. I checked by eliminating the missing and got the same results for the beta estimated parameters.